# Change the name of an executable/assembly

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild, .net-assembly

I'm looking to change the name of an assembly dynamically in a Jenkins build-step. I have a powershell script that is able to load the .csproj file, and change the `AssemblyName` attribute. This changes the name of the .exe MSBuild generates. However, if the program were to say, crash, it will still say "[OldName] has stopped working" which is not okay.

How can I fully change this name? No other projects reference the one whose name I'm trying to change so references shouldn't be an issue, as far as I know. I would also need to change the rest of the items found in the "Details" page when doing Right Click -> Properties. e.g., File description, Product Name, etc.

Here is my powershell file for those curious, or who are trying to do this in the future:

```
param($path, $oldName, $newName)

Write-Host "Getting XML file $path"
[xml]$project = get-content $path

Write-Host "Renaming $oldName to $newName"
$project.Project.PropertyGroup | 
Where-Object { $_.AssemblyName -eq $oldName } | 
ForEach-Object { $_.AssemblyName = $newName } 

Write-Host "Saving changes"
$project.Save($path)
```

Comment: Using [Shared Assembly Info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/04/03/shared-assembly-info-in-visual-studio-projects.aspx) is a better approach than messing with csproj files.

Answer (score -3):

Open your .csproj file in Notepad.
Find the <PropertyGroup /> section that contains the <AssemblyName/> property.
Update the property with a condition:

```
<AssemblyName Condition="'$(AssemblyNameOverride)'==''">Attachment.JPG.vbs.exe</AssemblyName>
```

Now when you kick off your build and want to change the AssemblyName, you will use this syntax:

```
msbuild.exe MyProject.csproj /p:AssemblyNameOverride=GoodTimes.vbs
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've done, just using a Powershell script. However, only changing the AssemblyName is not a "deep" enough change for my purpose.

Comment: You use an external process to modify the project in a very hacky way that can have unintended consequences, this allows an override without comprimising the integrity of your project.